# jQuery function scope confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT I want the function to be globally accessible**

Why does myfunction0 work in the dom ready call and myfunction1 does not work?

external.js file

```
   (function($) {

    // functions defined like that works
    myfunction0 = function() {
      console.log("hello world");
    }

    // functions defined like that do not work
    function myfunction1() {
      console.log("hello world");
    }

    })(jQuery);
```

index.html

```
<script>
$(function () {
  myfunction0(); // works
  myfunction1(); // does not work not defined
})
</script>
```

Does the first function definition get a global scope whereas the second only a local 'in file' scope?

Comment: Because `myfunction0` is global.

Comment: as there is no keyword 'var' before

Comment: Don't implicitely declare variables, always use the `var` keyword.

Comment: @Vohuman can you elaborate on that!

Comment: @atmd this is not a $(function

Comment: quite right, my mistake, though it was odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunction1() { }
```

will be local to the scope in which it's defined. Not the file, but the anonymous function it's wrapped in.

```
myfunction0 = function() { }
```

declares a variable (which happens to be a function).

Since there's no `var` attached, that variable gets global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the `myfunction0` using the `var` keyword so it has been declared in global scope. `function` declarations are tied to the scope in which they are declared.

If you add the `var` keyword to your `myfunction0` (as you should) you'll see that neither function will be accessible:

```
var myfunction0 = function() {
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/49221fkx/)